# Using bash in WebStorm terminal

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, webstorm

I downloaded git bash for Windows and attempted to set this as the shell in WebStorm. I went to `Settings -> Tools -> Terminal`, and set the Shell path to `git-bash.exe`. Then, when I pressed OK an opened the terminal in WebStorm, I got the message:

> Cannot open Local Terminal
> Failed to start [git-bash.exe] in C:\Users...
> Error running process: CreateProcess failed. Code 2

Perhaps I need the environmental variables set up but I wasn't sure how this would be done.

What steps are needed in order to enable this shell in the WebStorm terminal?

Answer (score 4):

Please use `full\path\to\Git\bin\sh.exe` as **Shell path** in **Settings | Tools | Terminal**.
`git-bash.exe` won't work, because it is a terminal emulator for `sh` shell with its own window/UI, not a shell. WebStorm provides its own terminal emulator in **Terminal** tool window. It's impossible to integrate one terminal emulator inside another, because all integration is based on parsing ANSI/VT sequences from underlying shell.